# how to recursively create a tree of links to any files in a specific folder in docpad

Tags: javascript, docpad

I'm really new to docpad and would like to know how i can recursively create a tree of links to any files in a specific folder in docpad

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [`getFilesAtPath` template helper](http://docpad.org/docs/template-data#standard-template-helpers). With [eco](http://docpad.org/plugin/eco) it would look like this:

```
<% for file in @getFilesAtPath('blah').toJSON(): %>
    <a href="<%= file.url %>"><%= file.name %></a>
<% end %>
```